# How do I convert Python output results to JSON string using Python

Tags: python, json, output, analysis

This is my function call

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    a = head_tail()
    b = data_info_for_analysis()
    c = data_visualization_chart()
    d = missing_values_duplicates()
    e = mapping_yes_no()
    f = one_hot_encoding()
    g = outlier_identification()

    out2 = removing_outliers()
    h = droping, features = removing_unwanted_columns(out2)

    df_telecom_test, df_telecom_train, probs, clf = random_model_predictions(droping, features)

    i = logistic_model_prediction(df_telecom_train, df_telecom_test, features)
    j = decision_model_prediction(df_telecom_train, df_telecom_test, features)

    k = fpr_tpr_thresholds(df_telecom_test, probs, clf, features)
```

I am trying to save that object as a json file

```
filter = "JSON File (*.json)|*.json|All Files (*.*)|*.*||"
filename = a.SaveFileName("Save JSON file as", filter)

if filename:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(a, f)
```

I am getting this below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/volumata/PycharmProjects/Churn-Analysis/sample-object-json.py", line 429, in <module>
    filename = a.SaveFileName("Save JSON file as", filter)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SaveFileName'
```

I have tried another method also

```
def head_tail():
    ### Head of the data
    print(df_telecom.head(5))

    ### Tail of the data
    print(df_telecom.tail(5))

code_obj = head_tail()
dis.disassemble(code_obj)
```

After trying this above method, getting this error

```
cell_names = co.co_cellvars + co.co_freevars
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'co_cellvars'
```

Comment: The question is very unclear. What do you have now?

Comment: i need to convert my python results to json string. what should i do for that , i dono how to convert that as json results

Comment: If your output is json serializable like dict/list , you can use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to dump your results

Comment: I am converting the results to JSON

Comment: You need to return the result (not print it), then use `json.dumps(result)`.

Comment: I am getting this error , when i return the results and tried dumps methods. raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Comment: i have called the dump function at the end of my code

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar Did you check my answer?

Comment: yes i have checked your answer... but to_json is working fine for me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serialising a `pandas.DataFrame` into JSON you can use its [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) method. There are different formatting options:

```
>>> df
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
>>> df.to_json()
'{"0":{"0":"a","1":"c"},"1":{"0":"b","1":"d"}}'
>>> df.to_json(orient='values')
'[["a","b"],["c","d"]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is very unclear. If you just want to convert some data from python-standard-types you can simply [use json.dump](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#basic-usage):

```
someResults = { ... }

import json
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
     json.dump(someResults, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: That "someResults" is there as a function, so how to pass that function to get as json file

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar: `someResults` is just a sample-variable, since at the time I posted this answer, you didn't provided any detailed information, about your structure. `someResults` can contain anything - it's just a placeholder.

Comment: yes, i know that its a variable ... im telling that my output results is stored as a function not in a variable. I am woundering how to pass the function to a json string.

Comment: well, return your output in the function then: `temp = functioncall()` and in the function you need to use `return`. See: [The return Statement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: i have already used this return statement in my function code... im not able to convert the python code results to a json file.

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar: well, show us what you've tried - all you provieded for us so far were custom-named-function calls - that doesn't help us

Comment: now i have edited what i have done so far, just check the above code and guide me, where it went wrong

Comment: @sangeethasivakumar: first off: formating! Read the provided help tool given in editor. Second: you can't delete the entire old question. This a part of the way to find the solution and even if i doubt any other will find this usefull this ignores all principles of this website. (sorry for drifting off-topic).
Read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and give it an other shot. I flag the question for closing now. It unlikely to provide value for others.